# Animeta: One True Pairing

Tags: knowledge, crosswords

*This is a crossword with an anime-themed meta. Which soft drink would complete the theme?*

[image: Crossword grid]

#### Clues

```
Across
1. Have ___ (lack the moves)
7. Some time ago
11. "Set phasers to ___"
15. "You just got burned!"
16. Start up, as a computer
17. Minase ("THE iDOLM@STER") or Nagase ("Kokoro Connect")
18. "A ___ Pass the Time" (translation for the opening of "CLANNAD ~After Story~")
19. Menu item at some Japanese restaurants
21. "Pokémon" character designer Sugimori
22. Inputs (data)
23. Non-winners
27. ___ of the Covenant
28. Kith's partner
31. Pick up (a skill)
32. Pallet Town's Ketchum
34. "Blend S" café, or steps over a fence
36. Truck weight unit
37. Lend a hand
39. "... ___ You Guys' Fault I'm Not Popular!"
42. Poses a question
43. Certain Astereae genus
47. Kitty feed
49. Produce, as an egg
50. Dec. 31
51. Affirmative reply
54. Real bad
56. Eggy seasonal drink
58. Shouko Nishimiya voice actress Hayami
60. Half of an expensive charge?
61. Wooden wish plaque at a Shinto shrine
64. Japanese photo sticker booth
66. "Don't ___", in the survival genre
68. Former competitor of Nvidia later acquired by AMD
69. Sitcom actor David
72. Triangular pastry with savoury filling
76. What an integral might compute
77. Lisa Simpson's grandmother
78. Rooted by heredity
79. One-named voice actress of the eponymous heroine in "Fuuka"
80. Word after martial or visual
81. Ermines with a brown fur phase

Down
1. Negative replies
2. "Well, lookee here!"
3. US channel that reruns programmes like "Family Feud"
4. ___ Wat
5. Motherly
6. "The Legend of Zelda" horse
7. Preoccupy
8. Chess or tic-tac-toe, e.g.?
9. ___ Rica
10. Early number?
11. Lancelot and Not-Appearing-In-This-Film, say
12. Overly
13. https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/, e.g.
14. Zero
20. Vexes
23. Certain modifier key
24. Shortest zodiac sign
25. Holy place that can be preceded by "inner"
26. "___: The Secret of Blue Water" (series directed by Hideaki Anno before Evangelion)
28. "Silver Spoon" first season opening, or a One Direction track
29. Kind or type
30. ___ Zapper (device for "Duck Hunt")
33. Successful turn in Battleship
35. 6.28, approximately
38. ___-gotten gains
40. Long-nosed creature in Japanese folklore
41. ___master (Codenames role)
44. Widely used symmetric-key algorithm for securing data
45. Counterpart to ACK when initialising a TCP connection
46. Slow in acting due to uncertainty
47. ___ mode (fashionable)
48. Universal gate
52. Be mistaken
53. "Angel By the Wings" and "Cheap Thrills" artist
55. Abominable Snowman
57. "Aida" and "Otello", for two
59. With hands on hips
62. "___ Mia!"
63. Cuirass, linothorax or neckguard, say
65. Navigator in Bemani's "SOUND VOLTEX"
66. "___ Lake" (Tchaikovsky ballet)
67. Blow off steam
69. Alternative to EMS or airmail
70. Call (out)
71. Small incubator
73. Commonly repeated 70-Down in "JoJo's Bizarre Adventure"
74. Commercial pastime with 81 cards
75. Pay-to-remove targets, in some apps
```

#### Across TEXT (for use with [Across Lite](http://www.litsoft.com/across/alite/download/))

```
<ACROSS PUZZLE V2>
<TITLE>
One True Pairing
<AUTHOR>
Sp3000
<COPYRIGHT>
2018
<SIZE>
16x15
<GRID>
XXXXXX.XXXX.XXXX
XXXXXX.XXXX.XXXX
XXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX
...XXX.XXXXXX...
XXXXXXXX.XXX.XXX
XXXXX.XXX..XXXXX
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXX
..XXXXXXXXXXXX..
XXXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
XXXXX..XXX.XXXXX
XXX.XXX.XXXXXXXX
...XXXXXX.XXX...
XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXX
XXXX.XXXX.XXXXXX
XXXX.XXXX.XXXXXX
<ACROSS>
Have ___ (lack the moves)
Some time ago
"Set phasers to ___"
"You just got burned!"
Start up, as a computer
Minase ("THE iDOLM@STER") or Nagase ("Kokoro Connect")
"A ___ Pass the Time" (translation for the opening of "CLANNAD ~After Story~")
Menu item at some Japanese restaurants
"Pokemon" character designer Sugimori
Inputs (data)
Non-winners
___ of the Covenant
Kith's partner
Pick up (a skill)
Pallet Town's Ketchum
"Blend S" cafe, or steps over a fence
Truck weight unit
Lend a hand
"... ___ You Guys' Fault I'm Not Popular!"
Poses a question
Certain Astereae genus
Kitty feed
Produce, as an egg
Dec. 31
Affirmative reply
Real bad
Eggy seasonal drink
Shouko Nishimiya voice actress Hayami
Half of an expensive charge?
Wooden wish plaque at a Shinto shrine
Japanese photo sticker booth
"Don't ___", in the survival genre
Former competitor of Nvidia later acquired by AMD
Sitcom actor David
Triangular pastry with savoury filling
What an integral might compute
Lisa Simpson's grandmother
Rooted by heredity
One-named voice actress of the eponymous heroine in "Fuuka"
Word after martial or visual
Ermines with a brown fur phase
<DOWN>
Negative replies
"Well, lookee here!"
US channel that reruns programmes like "Family Feud"
___ Wat
Motherly
"The Legend of Zelda" horse
Preoccupy
Chess or tic-tac-toe, e.g.?
___ Rica
Early number?
Lancelot and Not-Appearing-In-This-Film, say
Overly
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/, e.g.
Zero
Vexes
Certain modifier key
Shortest zodiac sign
Holy place that can be preceded by "inner"
"___: The Secret of Blue Water" (series directed by Hideaki Anno before Evangelion)
"Silver Spoon" first season opening, or a One Direction track
Kind or type
___ Zapper (device for "Duck Hunt")
Successful turn in Battleship
6.28, approximately
___-gotten gains
Long-nosed creature in Japanese folklore
___master (Codenames role)
Widely used symmetric-key algorithm for securing data
Counterpart to ACK when initialising a TCP connection
Slow in acting due to uncertainty
___ mode (fashionable)
Universal gate
Be mistaken
"Angel By the Wings" and "Cheap Thrills" artist
Abominable Snowman
"Aida" and "Otello", for two
With hands on hips
"___ Mia!"
Cuirass, linothorax or neckguard, say
Navigator in Bemani's "SOUND VOLTEX"
"___ Lake" (Tchaikovsky ballet)
Blow off steam
Alternative to EMS or airmail
Call (out)
Small incubator
Commonly repeated 70-Down in "JoJo's Bizarre Adventure"
Commercial pastime with 81 cards
Pay-to-remove targets, in some apps
<NOTEPAD>
Which soft drink would complete the theme?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Crossword Solution

> [image]

## Meta

> The theme answers are SUSHI ROLL, ALSO-RANS, CALLISTEPHUS, PURIKURA, and SCHWIMMER. These hide characters from No Game No Life:
>
>  SU**SHIRO**LL
>  AL**SORA**NS
>  CALLI**STEPH**US
>  PU**RIKU**RA
>  **SCHWI**MMER
>
>  The first three (Shiro, Sora, and Steph) are characters from the original No Game No Life. The last two (Riku and Schwi) are characters from No Game No Life Zero who are related to the Shiro and Sora: the corresponding character for Steph is named Couronne, so [**COLA COURONNE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cola_Couronne) is the answer.